# SCR3310v2.0 and SLE5528 read/write?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have SCR3310v2.0 reader and chip card SLE5528, There are any code samples to be able to record and read the card information, or is there are any free software who do it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using ACR38 so it may be a little different.

If you just started with smartcards, you should defiantly get some SDK (which is basically what you're asking for).

As for the SLE5528:
The card is really basic, there are 3 commands which you want to be aware of.

1)**Read**, can use this command anytime (as long as you're connected). with the ACR38, I will send this command:

```
FF B2 MSB LSB Length
```

This is an **[APDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit)** command,  the first byte named **CLA** and the second is **INS**. these two are usually used to describe the command (maybe always). then you have **P1** and **P2**, these two bytes are usually used to describe the address on the card or the range of the command. the last one is **Lc**, in that case (maybe always) it represents the number of bytes to read. any byte after these, is a data byte which a command may require.

Note that because this industry is so wild, some manufacturers may use different commands. If I remember correctly, the manual I used specified B0 in the INS  but in the SDK demo code they used B2 which also was the only thing that worked.

2)**Verify PSC**, you must use this command first if you plan to use the write command. (once for each session).

```
FF 20 00 00 02 PSC1 PSC2
```

Usually the default PSC code is FF FF.

3)**Write**, after verifying with the card you can execute this command to write data:

```
FF D0 MSB LSB Length DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 and so on.....
```

If I wanted to change the PSC code, all I had to do is to write it's three byte into the address 03 FD. note that the actual verification code is only two bytes, but for some reason I always need to write the first byte as FF and then the actual two bytes which I want to verify with. I believe that there is some reason behind this, I just don't know what it is.

So, to write a simple program which first reads 14 bytes from address A4 03. then verify with the card using the default PSC code. and at last changes the PSC code to A2 B2; we will do this:

```
<< FF B2 A4 03 0E
>> FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 90 00
<< FF 20 00 00 02 FF FF
>> FF FF FF 90 00
<< FF D0 03 FD 03 FF A2 B2
>> FF A2 B2 90 00
```

Note that the reader will always return two additional bytes to what we're *expecting*. these two bytes called the SW code (or the status code). 90 00 means all good. you can find references for the meaning of each return code

here is the manual for the reader that I'm working with:
http://www.acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/PMA_ACR38x.pdf

If you can, use [java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/) as they have built in functions for working with smart cards, otherwise. you can do what I did and work with the [WinSCard](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/winscard_8h.html) API of windows.

Comment: does `SLE5528` have a unique ID? What is the APDU command for retrieving it?

Comment: @ITCaptain I don't remember if it has any pre written ID. Not sure if it helps, but I remember that in my implementation, I've just written my own generated ID or each new issued card at some selected address.

If you design a new system, then I suggest you consider using a contactless. the NTAG family are very cheap and are far more capable.

Comment: can you give me some HEX command on how to save my own generated ID into these cards? I'm totally new to this.

Comment: @ITCaptain it is a simple write operation and it is explained in my answer. If you find it too confusing, feel free to contact me by email eshyah@yahoo.com and I will try to help you.