# working with IC card reader and SLE5528 smart card

Tags: java, credit-card, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

Am having an IC contact card reader and SLE5528 smart cards.Am wondering how to get started working with these items really.

The reader is being read and i see no effect when i insert the smart card .

i also installed the smart card shell of opensmart from [http://www.openscdp.org/](http://openscdp.org/)

but i can't get to read any card reader with it.Am wondering whether it has compatibility issues.

Please i know i may have asked the question inappropriately, but am kindly asking anyone there to help me out on this.

Any relevant links or helpful information to get me started and done will be of great help
Thanks in-advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCR3310v2.0 and SLE5528 read/write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895072/scr3310v2-0-and-sle5528-read-write)

Comment: Could you please proof read your question before posting? I can understand if English is not your native language, but you also managed to misspell the smart card type and provide an invalid URL.

Comment: PS you are trying to talk using a shell that is targeting smart cards, not memory cards like the SLE5528...

Comment: @owlstead, am just wondering where to write those read and write commands on the first url u provided which i visited before posting this article. The main reason for the card am using is to have a program that enables communication with some hosted server and the client card. Am actually not sure about all the concepts because am a newbie to this topic.

So am wondering whether you could advice me on how to do this and at-least have a hello-world application working. Please, please, please, help me. thanks in-advance .

Comment: Hillary, I'm doing this as a service to the community, but I cannot provide individual help (also see the FAQ). Furthermore, I commonly work with processor cards, not memory cards - so I don't know the specs by heart.

Comment: Owlstead, on behalf of the concerned part of the community, am wondering whether you could have any bit of relevant information however little you may think it is, shared to us on how to get started. At-least any starting point would be great a thing.

Please help us on this, help us all. thanks.

Comment: Does it mean that the SLE5528 cards are not programmable or cannot be used to accomplish my task at hand?

Comment: I don't know, as I don't know the task you have at hand.

Comment: Owlstead, For the start, i would like this card to have a program in which whether the user inserts it in the card reader, the user is authenticated through a http request to the server to verify that the card belongs to him and is known by the system.

Comment: It's an extremely limited chip with a unique ID and some storage area, which is world readable but can be protected against writing (for what that is worth).

Comment: so how do i get to write on it. 
or what do i need to write a program on it.

Comment: See the other question, otherwise you just need some PCSC compatible reader & software, and some understanding of ISO 7816-4 would not hurt. You can find it or buy it online.

Comment: You cannot program the cards. They don't have a CPU.

Comment: So what would u advice if i wanted to come up with such a system that communicates with the server using a smart card. I mean which card type and reader would you recommend. Thanks.

Comment: But am still wondering how these people in our country are using them to make payments like fuel and other payments.

Comment: By ignoring security, I suppose, but if you don't mind I'm off to answer some other questions and doing some programming. Good luck with your smart card development.

Comment: ok, thank you for your cooperation in the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated earlier a 5528 is a memory card, no smart card. The smart card shell mentioned is only able to address real smart cards. Make sure, that your (unmentioned) reader is able to read memory cards at all and how. Neither PCSC nor the java framework as best knwon interfaces to cards will help you here (the latter one being targeted towards JavaCards). That nothing worth noting happens, when you insert a card in the reader is not so unusual - the maximum reaction to be expected is a LED flashing shortly (if the reader has one), comparable to putting a USB stick into the port. Since no standard software knows how to handle a card, there will be no further reaction.
Suggestion: search for "5528", "4428" articles here or "memory card" in wikipedia, and prepare  to invest some time and work.

Comment: Thanks for this i have a better understanding of the difference now between processor and memory cards.Thanks alot.