# SLE 4442 smart card and N88 card reader APDU command failed

Tags: smartcard

I have bought a EMV smart card reader and SLE 4442 cards from below link.

http://m.ebay.com/itm/Micro-USB-OTG-Contact-EMV-Smart-Chip-Card-Reader-Writer-For-Android-Mobile-Phone-/271627714453

I have created an application in android which can send APDUs to the card.  I get successful ATR.

ATR 3b 4f 00 53 6c 65 34 34 33 32 2d 34 32 3d a2 13 10 91

But when I send reading memory APDU it gives me command failed error 40 FE. 
SLE 4442 datasheet can be found here

http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/168859/SIEMENS/SLE4442.html

can someone tell me how can I construct right APDUs for

Reading
Writing
PIN creation
PIN verification ?

Comment: I sent 304500 APDU command for reading memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [working with IC card reader and SLE5528 smart card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145103/working-with-ic-card-reader-and-sle5528-smart-card)

Comment: The reader is different so is the driver and API.

Comment: @user1887469: While I agree that details are different, I supply that background information since you won't be able to make progress without it- neither the ATR, nor the error code nor the APDU you gave in the comment is helpful to anyone not having this special reader.

Comment: does ATR string has anything to do with APDU commands sent after ?

Comment: Please is there sdk for the N88 card reader or where can I find the doc to use in writing program for the reader

Answer (score 1):

You have no smart card, but a memory card. These cards understand no APDUs, since they have protocols like two-wire, three-wire, i2c. Some readers convert APDUs to the appropriate commands, but these APDUs are not universal but depend on the specific reader. As I understand from the ebay-offer you find either the documentation on the accompanying driver CD, by google or you have to find a better documented reader.

Comment: it doesn't have a documentation for sending commands to SLE 4442. Can you suggest me any OTG reader for android that is available online ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [guidot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967745/sle-4442-smart-card-and-n88-card-reader-apdu-command-failed/35969614#35969614), there is a PC/SC specification defining standardized access to storage cards. You may want to have a look [here](http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf).

Unfortunately only a few vendors implement this.

Definitely check your reader documentation -- they claim to support SLE4442 so they should tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your memory card before all.
I have a ACR38U reader, and work for me.

```
CLA    INS    P1    P2    P3    DATA

 - FF    A4    00    00    01    06        'INITIALIZE 
FF    B0    00 <BYTE-ADDR>    <LENGTH> (some string length=P3)   READ BYTE 
FF    20    00    00    03    <PSC CODE>    ENABLE WRITE 
FF    D0    00 <BYTE-ADDR>    <LENGTH>    <BYTES TO WRITE>   ' WRITE BYTES
```

and so on...