# Cannot read from memory card SLE5528

Tags: c#, winforms, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

I am still new on working with cards and card readers; I am using `C#` to build an application that is integrated with ACR38U Smart Card Reader and I have SLE5528 memory cards. I am using the following example to give unique ID to a memory card (`22222` in this case):

```
    int indx;

    tmpStr = "22222";
    ClearBuffers();

    SendBuff[0] = 0xFF;
    SendBuff[1] = 0xD0;
    SendBuff[2] = 0xA1;
    SendBuff[3] = 0x00;
    SendBuff[4] = 0x08;

    for (indx = 0; indx <= tmpStr.Length - 1; indx++)
    {
        if ((Convert.ToByte(tmpStr[indx])) != 0x00)
            SendBuff[indx + 5] = Convert.ToByte(tmpStr[indx]);
    }

    SendBuffLen = SendBuff[4] + 5;
    RecvBuffLen = 2;
    tmpStr = "";

    for (indx = 0; indx <= SendBuffLen - 1; indx++)
    {
        tmpStr = tmpStr + string.Format("{0:x2}", SendBuff[indx]).ToUpper() + " ";
    }

    retcode = SendAPDUandDisplay(0, tmpStr);

    if (retcode != ModWinsCard64.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
    {
        return;
    }

    tData.Text = "";
```

From where I get `90 00` response, which means success. And now I use this one to read from memory card:

```
    int indx;

    tData.Text = "";
    ClearBuffers();

    SendBuff[0] = 0xFF;
    SendBuff[1] = 0xB0;
    SendBuff[2] = 0xA1;
    SendBuff[3] = 0x00;
    SendBuff[4] = 0x08;

    SendBuffLen = 5;
    RecvBuffLen = SendBuff[4] + 2;
    tmpStr = "";

    for (indx = 0; indx <= SendBuffLen - 1; indx++)
    {
        tmpStr = tmpStr + string.Format("{0:x2}", (SendBuff[indx])).ToUpper() + " ";
    }

    retcode = this.SendAPDUandDisplay(2, tmpStr);

    if (retcode != ModWinsCard64.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
    {
        return;
    }

    // 3. Display data read from card into Data textbox
    tmpStr = "";

    for (indx = 0; indx <= SendBuff[4] - 1; indx++)
    {
        tmpStr = tmpStr + Convert.ToChar(RecvBuff[indx]);
    }
    tData.Text = tmpStr;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[RecvBuffLen];

    for (int i = 0; i < RecvBuffLen; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = RecvBuff[i];
    }

    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer2.Length; i++)
    {
        if (buffer.Length > i)
            buffer2[i] = buffer[i];
    }

    int iCardID = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer2, 0);
    MessageBox.Show(iCardID.ToString());
```

But `iCardID` is always `-1` instead of `22222`. Any ideas on where am I doing wrong? Maybe I am writing incorrectly.

Comment: Is the card encrypted?  Are you using the correct key to unlock the card?  Does the reader support the card you are using?  The reader software may be old and the card may be newer.  Can you read card from PC with different software?

Comment: @jdweng these cards came in the same SDK package with reader. I am using the code from those samples, but it just doesn't work the way I want. How do I know if the card is encrypted?

Comment: Most smart cards are encrypted.  Did you install the driver that came with device.  You may of installed the standard Microsoft driver instead of the manufacturers driver.  Is the card working when reading using a window explorer? Get windows working first.  Is reader on same machine as the Windows Form application?  From you description you could have an Android.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13145103/1435475). The SLE5528 is a dumb memory card, no encryption whatsoever.

Comment: @guidot can you please take a look if I'm doing a write function correct way? If yes, then I will work on reading the card.

Comment: @FireFalcon: The commands to be sent are determined by the reader/driver, and I did not anlayse ACS yet. If I remember correctly P1/P2 (SendBuff[2] and [SendBuff[3]) are encoding the offset: 0xA100 seems a bit large. (Real -asynchronous- smart cards may provide a special addressing mode with set MSB of P1 called *short EF identifier* which does not seem useful here - check reader documentation.)

Comment: @guidot is it normal that `SLE5528` takes 10 - 12 seconds to initialize, when you insert it into card reader?