# How to read SLE4428 smart card using S9 protocol in pyscard library

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, pyscard

I have a problem with reading SLE4428 card. I tried to use simple program written in python, but I received a message that pyscard supports only T=0 and T=1 protocol. My card uses S9 protocol.

Do you have any software which I can use to read/write data on SLE4428 card? Or maybe someone know how to read S9 protocol in pyscard library.

Comment: What is an S9 protocol? Could you include a reference to the standard? I see a dual interface smart card reader called S9, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLE44xx are memory cards using an ancient two-wire protocol. Some readers translate special APDUs to the respective hardware signals, but which commands you have to use may depend on the reader. (I never tried to use pyscard for that task and suggest, to consider using a newer technology than memory card).

Note that SLE44xx and SLE55xx are identical in this respect and you may find additional information in other questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56198857/1435475) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31850578/1435475).