# ACR38U-I1 Android Driver: Can't read key from infineon SLE4428 Smart card

Tags: android, smartcard, acr

I've downloaded the ACR38U-I1 android driver from the [official page](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/199/acr38u-i1-smart-card-reader/). The the downloaded zip file there is a sample apk to test the reader. My tried to read a infineon SLE4428 card with the sample app.
I followed these steps:

- Connect the ACR38U-I1 reader to my android phone
- Open the android app, then i can see the connected reader
- Click "Open" to open the reader
- Insert the card into the slot
- "Warm Reset" the card
- Click "Read Key"

but then the log shows `InvalidArgumentException` - The control code `2080` is invalid

[image]

How can i read the card ? Please help.

Comment: While this reader should be able to read memory cards like SLE4428, I have no idea, what the command *read key* should do with such a memory card, which has no key whatsoever. So it seems the sample app mismatches the card you try to handle.

Comment: So i think I need to transmit a command to read the content of the card. Can you share how to read/write to this card ?

Comment: Start at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145103/working-with-ic-card-reader-and-sle5528-smart-card).

Comment: Thanks @guidot, It helped a lot. Can i ask you a little favor ? I can't understand how SLE4428 PSC verification works, Can i write into the card without PSC verification?. Can you guide me with some links? Thanks in advance